# Is the conservativity of a force frame independent? If so, how do you show it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, potential-energy, conservative-field

If a force $\vec{f}$ is conservative in a frame $S$, is it such in another, generic, frame of reference $S'$? How do you show this, and how are the potential energies in the two frames related?

Comment: Can I recommend eliminating "non-inertial frames" from your question? It just makes the answer have too many caveats. One would have to say "well do I include the fictitious forces of my non-inertial frame as a separate force, or do they get included in the force field $\vec{f}$, making it non-conservative in a kind of trivial way." This question may be advanced for you, but you should also clarify whether or not you're at the level of education where you're aware of special relativity - are your reference frames "gallilean" or "relativistic" (velocity differences near the speed of light)

Comment: I don't know SR, I am currently studying classical mechanics, so with "reference frames" I mean galilean ones.

Comment: To be clear, I don't think the answer is different whether its Galilean or relativistic, but clarifying that will prevent people answering your question with notation you don't understand.

Comment: What is a generic reference frame $~S'~$ can you write the definition ?

Comment: It is a reference frame moving away from the $S$ frame.

Answer (score 2):

In Newtonian mechanics, cartesian force component has the same value in all inertial frames, so if a force field is conservative in one frame, it is conservative in all frames.

In special relativity, cartesian force component is not the same in all inertial frames; and the transformation depends on the relative velocity of the frames. So even if force field is conservative in one frame S, it is, in general, not conservative in a frame S' that is moving with respect to S. For example, electrostatic force in S' becomes mix of moving electric and magnetic force in S', and both these fields in S' are not conservative.

Comment: How can I show this mathematically? For the galilean case I mean.

Comment: What is there to show? The field is the same in all frames.

Comment: While I see that the field is the same, I don't get how, from the definition of a conservative force in $S$, I can prove that the definition is satisfied for every frame. For example, let $\vec{f}$ be a force such that on every closed path, in $S$, the work of $\vec{f}$ is 0. How do I conclude that the work on a generic closed path, wrt $S'$, is also 0?

Comment: Work here is integral of the dot product of field vector and displacement vector over closed path, done at a single time. Force has the same value in all frames, and displacement has the same value in all frames. Thus the product has the same value in all frames, and the integral has the same value in all inertial frames.

Comment: Real displacement takes some time, but when judging whether field is conservative, we express the work integral as if the motion happens at a single time and that makes the integral the same in all frames.

Comment: Isn't work frame dependent? If so, how can the integral be the same?

Comment: Real work per unit time is frame dependent, e.g. when the force acts on a real body, work done during unit time interval depends on the frame, because real displacement of the body depends on the frame. Here, however, we only have an expression that looks like real work, but it is not real work, because there is no moving body, and no time progression. Thus the displacement in the integral is not displacement of a real body, but it is a change of integration variable and this is the same in both frames.

Comment: In other words, field being conservative does not mean that when real body moves and makes one turn along the closed path, real work is zero. It means work-like integral of the force along the closed path, done at single time instant, is zero.